# sql "SELECT INTO" but also with custom values

Tags: sql, database

EDIT: hopefully this is a better explenaition.

I have 2 values from my html form which are the schoolName and the className, I am trying to insert the className into the class table at the beginning, after that is inserted I want to retrieve the schoolID from the table school where the schoolName = the schoolname i got from the html form. Lastly i want to insert into the table schoolclass (NULL, "the schoolID we selected before", "the classID from the inserted classname at the first step")

Answer (score 1):

You could use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.

Like so:

```
INSERT INTO schoolclass
SELECT 'value1', schoolID, 'value3'
FROM school;
```

Comment: sorry if i havent explained it well enough, the value1 and value3 are not from the school table, they are values i got from a html form.

Comment: Apologies, I used the wrong quotes. I changed it into single quotes - you can always use constants/literals or expressions in the column list of a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I do not want to select 'value1' and 'value3' from the database, these are 2 values i got from my form, I only need to select the schoolID value and then insert the 2 already known values from my form + the selected schoolID and insert them into the "schoolclass" table

Answer (score 0):

Continuing Hellmar's answer, you need something like this

```
INSERT INTO schoolclass (field1, field2, field3)
SELECT knownvalue1, school.schoolID, knownvalue2
FROM school
WHERE <condition>;
```

where knownvalue1 and knownvalue2 are - as far as the query is concerned - constants. You would have to derive these from your HTML form. I don't think that there is enough information to give a more complete answer, so a simple answer would be: yes, you can insert constant values along with varying values into a table.